# Dynamic javascript error

Tags: c#, javascript, dynamic, code-behind

I'm trying to make a dynamic javascript from code behind that would be added to the page and would enable thus a little jwplayer to open up, my code so far:

```
void playAudioFile(string path)
    {
        string script =
        @"    var div = document.getElementById('playerDiv');
              var audio = document.createElement('audio');
              audio.setAttribute('id', 'audioPlayer');
              div.appendChild(audio);

              jwplayer(""audioPlayer"").setup({
              file: 'http://ps.staging.be/webservice/MP3DownloadHandler.ashx?id='" + path +
              @"'&date=' + '<%=Encrypt.EncryptString(String.Format(""{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"",
              DateTime.UtcNow))%>',
              width: ""100%"",
              height: ""30"",
              type: 'mp3',
              stretching: ""uniform"",
              controlbar: 'bottom'
          });
    ";

    //Add the script to it's tags
    HtmlGenericControl playScript = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
    playScript.InnerHtml = script;
    //Add it on his place
    playerDiv.Controls.Add(playScript);
```

But this turns out to a "could not make contact with localhost:55323 does anyone know what mistake I make? + is there a better way? The purpose would be to display a player if a person clicked on an element on my website, and the players path would change on hand of the selected item. I'm kinda making a system like youtube if you want something to compare with.

Final Solution

---

```
string date = Encrypt.EncryptString(String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.UtcNow));
    string script =
    @"    var div = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_playerDiv');
          var audio = document.createElement('audio');
          audio.setAttribute('id', 'audioPlayer');
          div.appendChild(audio);

          jwplayer(""audioPlayer"").setup({
              file: 'http://ps.staging.be/webservice/MP3DownloadHandler.ashx?id=" + path + @"&date=" + date + @"', 
              width: '100%',
              height: '30',
              type: 'mp3',
              stretching: 'uniform',
              controlbar: 'bottom'
          });
    ";

    //Add the script to it's tags
    HtmlGenericControl playScript = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
    playScript.InnerHtml = script;
    //Add it on his place
    playerDiv.Controls.Add(playScript);
```

Comment: This is really not a good way to do this. HTML and Javascript don't belong in the code-behind. And putting script blocks in it *definitely* won't work. You should look into making custom UserControls

Comment: Isn't the point of a usercontrol to get data from it to put it into the actual page? Rather then taking data from the actual page to update the UC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using [ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "FooKey", script, true);
```

You have a code block inside the script, not sure why you don't build that string in code and then append it to the script:

```
string date = Encrypt.EncryptString(String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.UtcNow));
string script =
    @"    var div = document.getElementById('playerDiv');
          var audio = document.createElement('audio');
          audio.setAttribute('id', 'audioPlayer');
          div.appendChild(audio);
          jwplayer(""audioPlayer"").setup({
          file: 'http://ps.staging.be/webservice/MP3DownloadHandler.ashx?id='" + path +  @"'&date=" + date + ", width: '100%', height: '30',type: 'mp3', stretching: 'uniform',controlbar: 'bottom'});";
```

Comment: Even this wont work. He's got a code block inside the `script` variable

Comment: Didn't see that - bit of an odd thing to do. Will edit

Comment: I'd like it to be less-odd but I'm really bad at javascripting and I can't find anyone trying to do what I do to get a basic idea of what to do. It's as if except youtube, dailymotion and those sites no one even tries to make a collection of videos on their site that you can play one by one by clicking on them. Atleast not on mobile. The purpose of mine would be to be displayed on mobile devices

Comment: What you're trying to do isn't odd in and of itself. It was the embedding of a codeblock in the script when you could have quite easily just generated the string outside of the script in the code behind

Comment: Sadly this still gives an error on the link-part of the script. And my link looks pretty odd if I inspect it later on in firefox: file: 'http://ps.staging.be/webservice/MP3DownloadHandler.ashx?id='eGdGZTBwWFZvU1FzUXVGN2o2UGQvU2VzUFhDK1BuTDFDNWFpa1VzbzlndGNMRU56aVNHemhRPT01'&date=bnlUK0FvK21wTW8vUHI3aE03Q3EzUT090' this is what it should be, except that he didn't pick the path as a completing string but he bracks it out, and I just can't fix that. I edited my post to the code that I have on this moment

Comment: This was quite a stupid thing to say, fixed that problem by moving some brackets, thought that because it made it all blue that it wouldn't take the script correctly but it did. Last error left now is: "Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null" so I've got a nullpointexception now :s

Comment: @Akorna That error means that your `div` object was not found by `document.getElementById('playerDiv');`. This is probably a separate question

Comment: Indeed, asp renamed my div for no apparent reason to: ContentPlaceHolder1_playerDiv. now that I found this error everything plays like it should, thanks a lot for the help. Now I should find another way to do it, because on mobile you need too many clicks.... getting out of ideas but that would be my problem ^^ Thanks again!

Comment: Happy to help. If this answers your question, you should accept it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can not add scriptlet in the string and assign it to some controls InnerHtml. 
 I would write javascript directly to aspx (html) side as I belive that is simple and more straight forward.

*Change*

```
+ '<%=Encrypt.EncryptString(String.Format(""{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"", DateTime.UtcNow))%>',
```

*To*

```
+ Encrypt.EncryptString(String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.UtcNow))
```

Comment: Thing is, I'd love to do this in the innerHtml itself but the player shouldn't be displayed if firstly there wasn't an item selected and I don't know how to push forward an argument to the script if it's already in the innerhtml. And what you just suggested should do the trick but it still gives me an unexpected error.

Comment: No error anymore, solved it with the answers above :) but what you gave did it too ^^

Comment: And I don't have the reputation needed to up your answer anyway :(

Comment: No worries dear... I think you will get that reputation soon.